# VB6 - Select a single node using XPATH with backslashes, underscores

Tags: xml, xpath, vb6

Been a while since I used VB.  I am having a problem running an XPATH query on some XML.

I have the following XML:

```
<configuration>
    <my.app.application>
        <dummydatasets>
            <dummydataset tag="\\server\XX_YY_ZZ" />
            <dummydataset tag="default" mode="random" />
        </dummydatasets>
    </my.app.application>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to find the dummy data set using XPATH.  The XPATH to evaluate is:

**//configuration/my.app.application/dummydatasets/dummydataset [@tag="\\server\XX_YY_ZZ"]**

So that is double backslash, "server", slash, "XX_YY_ZZ".

The VB6 code is as follows:

```
Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
If xmlDoc.Load(path to xml) Then

    Dim theTag As String
    theTag = "\\server\XX_YY_ZZ"
    Dim xPathQuery As String
    xPathQuery = "//configuration/my.app.application/dummydatasets/dummydataset [@tag='" & theTag & "']"
    Set xmlNode = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode(xPathQuery)

End If
```

The tag cannot be found.  xmlNode is set to Nothing.  However using a utility such as XML Copy Editor, I can enter the XPATH and the node is found.  However, if I select the default tag, the code works fine.

I didn't think there would be a problem with the tag attribute's text with the backslash and underscores.  I am hopefully wrong.

Any thoughts,

Thanks

Andez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this and the issue is with the backslashes. Underscores were fine but the backslashes caused issues.

You need to specify the **SelectionLanguage** in DOMDocument after it is created:

```
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

Here is the [source page](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-xml/67/Problem-selecting-a-node-with-XPATH-if-attribute-value-contains).

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  Will give it a go.  At the minute I am replacing \ with \\ and it seems to work for now.