# VB6 DOMDocument Find a Specific Comment and Delete

Tags: vb6, comments, domdocument

VB6 on Win8.1
Microsoft XML v3.0

I have searched in vain -I can search elements in a xml file using VB6 but I cannot figure out how to search for a specific comment in an xml file and delete it.

I found a great [VB6 XML tutorial](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/07/12/vbasic/example.html) - some sample code below to load nodes into treeview/WebBrowser controls as an example of the type of code I am working with:

```
Private Sub cmdPopulate_Click()
  Dim objPeopleRoot As IXMLDOMElement
  Dim objPersonElement As IXMLDOMElement
  Dim tvwRoot As Node
  Dim X As IXMLDOMNodeList

  Set m_objDOMPeople = New DOMDocument

  'this can stop the m_objDOMPeople object from looking
  'for external files which in our case are the people.dtd
  'and the people.xsl files - set this to true if you want
  'the parser to look for the external files
  m_objDOMPeople.resolveExternals = True

  'this can stop the m_m_objDOMPeople from validating the XML file
  'against the people.dtd file - set this to true if you want validation to
  'occur
  m_objDOMPeople.validateOnParse = True

  'load the XML into the dom document, using a string containing
  'the XML location
  m_objDOMPeople.async = False
  Call m_objDOMPeople.Load(m_strXmlPath)

  'check that the load of the XML document was successful
  If m_objDOMPeople.parseError.reason <> "" Then
    ' there has been an error with the loaded XML - show the reason
    MsgBox m_objDOMPeople.parseError.reason
    Exit Sub
  End If

  'get the root element of the XML - bypassing the comments, PI's etc
   Set objPeopleRoot = m_objDOMPeople.documentElement

  'Now lets populate the treecontrol from the DOMDocument

  'Set Treeview control properties.
  tvwPeople.LineStyle = tvwRootLines
  tvwPeople.Style = tvwTreelinesPlusMinusText
  tvwPeople.Indentation = 400

  'check if the treeview has already been populated - if so
  'remove the root, which removes everything.
  If tvwPeople.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
    tvwPeople.Nodes.Remove 1
  End If

  ' add a child to the root node of the TreeView
  Set tvwRoot = tvwPeople.Nodes.Add()
  tvwRoot.Text = objPeopleRoot.baseName

  'iterate through each element in the dom to fill the tree,
  'which in itself iterates through each childNode of that
  'element(objPersonElement) to drill down into its childNodes
  For Each objPersonElement In objPeopleRoot.childNodes
    populateTreeWithChildren objPersonElement
  Next

  webTarget.Navigate m_strXmlPath
  cmdDelete.Enabled = True
  cmdClear.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I have found COMMENT_NODE - 8 on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodetype.asp) but I am not sure how to use that in VB6

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Using Bob's code

I call it in the following way - is this correct? It iterates through and seems to find every .nodetype BUT comments. I am quite sure this is operator error - if I am calling DeleteTargetComments incorrectly - passing in the wrong object - what is the correct way?

```
Private m_objDOMPeople As DOMDocument

Private Sub cmdRemoveComments_Click()

    ' DeleteTargetComments DOM.documentElement

    Dim objPeopleRoot As IXMLDOMElement

    Set objPeopleRoot = m_objDOMPeople.documentElement

    DeleteTargetComments objPeopleRoot
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at how XPATH is used in this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836590/vb6-select-a-single-node-using-xpath-with-backslashes-underscores

Comment: Jac, Thank you for responding - will check it out

Comment: That looks correct, though more "chatty" than required (no need for a separately-declared and set variable).  I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of features in MSXML are really there to help optimize use in a slow scripting language.  XPath is one of these, and often it gains you very little except complexity.  Any performance advantage it might have on very long documents is blown away by avoiding the use of a DOM at all and simply moving to SAX parsing instead.

So if you are dealing with fairly small XML documents a VB6 program can do this pretty simply.

Original XML:

```
<doc>
    <item>a</item><!-- target to delete -->
    <!-- to keep -->
    <item>b<!-- target to delete too --></item>
</doc>
```

You can just use:

```
Private Sub DeleteTargetComments(ByRef Parent As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode)
    Dim Children As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim Node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    Set Children = Parent.childNodes
    'We must check .length because in MSXML the collection iterators are broken:
    If Children.length > 0 Then
        For Each Node In Children
            With Node
                If .nodeType = NODE_COMMENT Then
                    If InStr(LCase$(.Text), "target") Then
                        Parent.removeChild Node
                    End If
                Else
                    DeleteTargetComments Node
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

And invoke it as:

```
DeleteTargetComments DOM.documentElement
```

Result:

```
<doc>
    <item>a</item><!-- to keep -->
    <item>b</item>
</doc>
```

Pretty straightforward, though full whitespace preservation is another subject.

Comment: Bob77 - Thank you for responding - will check this out - still trying to figure stuff out in vb6. Like the use of MSXML2 - once I get that done I will be good to go I think. EDIT: What I mean is figuring out how to reference MSXML2 - I am aware I might be over complicating things though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  You can set a reference to `Microsoft XML, v3.0` or `Microsoft XML, v6.0` (both work, but don't try to use any 4.0 or 5.0 you see which are obsolete and MS-Office-specific respectively).